# Database dashboard with auto refresh and pagination

Tags: laravel

I have a database project with several tables and want to create a dashboard showing 4 data tables with individual pagination. This dashboard should refresh every 10 seconds automatically without any user interaction and should also increase every page number on those tables. What do you think, would be the best way to implement that functionality?  How to implement auto refresh?  How to increase that page number and at the last page jump back to the first?

thx for help. I am new to Laravel and WebDev

Comment: This is an opinion question an as such should not be on stack overflow. However, if it were me, I would use Livewire and use the polling feature to update the data. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/polling 

You could also use any other JS framework like Vue or React and make regular requests to the backend to get the data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.